# Restrict wifi access during time periods

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-firewall

I need to block all access to a Wi-Fi hotspot to all devices (that already have previously connected and to any new devices that will connect) within a certain time frame e.g 8:30-13:00 on Sundays. While only allow one computer to use the network and two or three Android devices.

The rest of the time anyone can connect.

I mean an easy way would be to change the password twice but I would rather want an automatic way.

Is there a way of using Windows 10 firewall to do this?
EDIT I forgot to mention I connect to a booster and the booster connects to a **(Vodafone) Huawei HHG2500** router. So I'm actually not sure if applying settings to the router will help I would probably have to access the booster and see what features it provides?

Or a different approach while the computer is on only the first two devices that connect can connect and the rest are automatically blocked?

The main issue is that the connection lags so I need to prioritise bandwidth for the computer.

Comment: What's the make and model of the wi-fi hot spot device? You'd likely need to use functionality built into it to do this based on mac address, etc. assuming it has such functionality.

Comment: I don't have physical access to the device at the moment. I'm not exactly sure. Its a Virgin Media router. But if it's like mine then its built in features are no where near sufficient. My own router (although not a virgin router) can only block devices by Mac Address but it has no support for time frames.

Comment: Are you telling from 8.30 -13:00. wifi should available for all user/device who connects. Rest of the time only one device should connected?.

Comment: The inverse. You can connect at all times. But during 8:30-13:00 only one computer and two smartphones can connect.

Comment: you are using windows 10 feature mobile hotspot right?

Comment: Nope, the PC simply connects to a wifi booster (which is the connection I need to restrict).

Comment: So that WI fi booster is nothing but your Physical Router Virgin Media router. So all Devices are connected to Virgin Router for wi fi access. which model number can you share the details. a

Comment: I'll try and get the model and post back asap

Comment: Posted the router model.